# How to "hook in" puppeteer into a running Chrome instance/tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

Is it somehow possible to attach puppeteer to a running Chrome instance (manually started browser) and then takeover control within a tab?  I'm assuming that it's eventually related to start the Chrome browser using the `--no-sandbox` flag but don't know how to continue from there.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `puppeteer.connect(options)` (see [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions)):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browserWSEndpoint = 'a browser websocket endpoint to connect to';
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint});
//continue from here
```

Comment: Cool Thanks that was what I was looking for. Also wroth to mention here that chrome must be started using the `--remote-debugging-port=A_PORT_NUMBER` flag (which was written in the linked documentation.